# Mapper does not contain a definition for Initialize AutoMapper C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have implement Auto Mapper in my asp.net C# project but i got the error:

> > Mapper does not contain a definition for Initialize

I've tried this example [Link Here](http://technotipstutorial.blogspot.com/2018/03/part-52-how-to-use-automapper-in-aspnet.html)

I've paste my code:

```
namespace NewsWeb.Web.Infrastructure
{
    public class AutomapperWebProfile:Profile
    {
        public AutomapperWebProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<DistrictDTO, District>().ReverseMap();
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(a =>
            {
                a.AddProfile<AutomapperWebProfile>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In my Golbal.asax.cs file:

```
 AutomapperWebProfile.Run();
```

Error image:
[image]

Comment: If you're using v9+ the static API has been removed: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Method `Mapper.Initialize` is obsolete since version v9.0.0 ([doc](https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.1.0/Static-and-Instance-API.html)), you need to use `MapperConfiguration` instead ([doc](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)).

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<AutomapperWebProfile>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

Initializing a mapper with a static method in a Golbal.asax is not a flexible solution. I would suggest creating a config directly in the custom mapper class.

```
public interface IFooMapper 
{   
    Foo Map(Bar bar); 
}

public class FooMapper : IFooMapper
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public FooMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<FooProfile>();
        });

        mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    public Foo Map(Bar bar) => mapper.Map<Foo>(bar);
}
```

Comment: How can i use this in Global.asax file ?

Comment: I have added the answer to this question.